# Can spring data elasticsearch join parent and child relationship?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

```
{
   "properties":{
      "id":{
         "type":"text",
         "fields":{
            "keyword":{
               "ignore_above":256,
               "type":"keyword"
            }
         }
      },
      "username":{
         "type":"text",
         "fields":{
            "keyword":{
               "ignore_above":256,
               "type":"keyword"
            }
         }
      },
      "parentId":{
         "type":"text",
         "fields":{
            "keyword":{
               "ignore_above":256,
               "type":"keyword"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

for example I have a user:
 id:1,
 username: admin,
 parentId: null

I have another user:
 id:5,
 username:manager,
 parentId:1

I have another user:
 id:10,
 username:staff001,
 parentId:5

If I query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "*staff*",
      "default_field": "*"
    }
  }
}
```

my expected result is staff001 and his parent's detail

Is it possible to do this on spring data elasticsearch?

I am sure that it is possible to do this on spring jpa mapping using @OneToOne or @ManyToOne (for example mysql/postgresql)